# Managing and storing an artifact/library (e.g. a jar) used by an Heroku/Cloudfoundry application

Tags: heroku, jar, cloud-foundry, 12factor

I have read the 12-factor-app manifesto and I have the following interrogation: where and how can I store a in-house library such a jar that is going to be consumed by several of my Heroku or Cloudfoundry apps?

All of this bearing in mind that the codebase for that library/jar is versioned in Github.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a file store such as OpenStack Swift (it has an S3 compatible API as well.  You could also use CouchDB and store attachments in a DB record as well.

Comment: Thanks jsloyer. However I am looking for a solution that can also address concerns such as artifact version and Id (think maven/gradle)...

Comment: So you want to share a jar between multiple apps?

Comment: Yes. an in-house library.

Comment: Im kinda confused by want you want...  You can't really deference a shared location for a jar file at run time.  The jar file has to be built into the war file.  What you could do is when you build your war file have a shared project that has your shared deps and reference that shared project when you build your war file

Comment: By sharing I meant consumed by different apps. So there would be different copies of the same jar living in different webapps. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: Yeah that is the only way you can do it, you have to have the same jar in different web apps, there is no way to have a central shared jar location.

Comment: Umm.. My question was really how to have a kindof cloud-located artifactory/nexus?

Comment: You can't do that with Java.  You can't pull in dependencies at run time.

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't anything like that that I have seen yet in java.  You can't have dynamic dependency injection in java, its something you can't do.